# React - Change in one object reflects on another even though its not modified

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change the value for an Object reflects on another if I assign the same object to two state objects. For example service returns the data like below

```
formData = {
  'name':'name',
  'data':{
    'value':'value',
    'isactive':false
    }
};
```

I am trying to assign the same object to two different state objects

```
this.setState({ 
  formdata: formdata,
  initialFormData : formdata
});
```

If I modify anything on formdata reflects on initialFormData.
I mapped formdata with form. If I modify name it should reflect only on formdata but it also modifies initialFormData but I dont want my initialFormData not to be changed bec I need to reset the whole data with the initialFormData if any one clicks on reset button.

How to achieve the same . Please help me on this . Thanks in advance

If you need more info comment below . I can provide the same.

Answer (score 2):

Initial `setState` (data from service) saves references to one (base) object. This way both values are pointers to the same data. **This can be done that way (for initial render) - problem is with field handlers, mutating state methods**.

Your handler by accessing `this.state.formdata` gets pointer to base object. Mutating this changes this object, not (as you want) value (object) stored in `this.state.formdata`.

```
let formdata = this.state.formdata; // OLD REFERENCE
formdata[field] = evt.value; // THIS WAY YOU"RE MUTATING BASE OBJECT
this.setState({ formdata: formdata }); // STILL THE SAME REFERENCE
```

You need to prepare a **new object** (deep clone) and use it in `setState()`

```
let newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( this.state.formdata ));
newObj[field] = evt.value;
this.setState({ formdata: newObj });
```

**Deep clone is needed** as your base object `formData` contains `data` object. Usual methods (assign, spread) are doing shallow copy - they will copy `data` reference. This way f.e. mutating `data.isActive` will still affect both values in state.

Read [article](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/copying-objects-in-javascript) about differences.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this:

```
// outside the class
const initialFormData = {
  // your initial data
}
// inside the class
state = {
  formData: initialFormData
}
// when you want to update with initial data
this.setState({
  formData: initialFormData
})
```

Comment: No . I need to maintain copy of two objects from service ie formdata & initial formdata and assigned the same . But if i modify any one formdata changes reflects on initialformdata . I want to know how to avoid it

Comment: The answer should satisfy your requirement. Please let me know why not?

Comment: It works for me at the first time . and if i modify the same second time changes reflects on both the objects

Comment: why would initialFormData be changed? No. It won't.

Answer (score 0):

This works. You want the form data object copied for both items in state. So this will work fine.

```
  let formData = {
  'name':'name',
  'data':{
  'value':'value',
  'isactive':false
 }
}; 

let State = { 

 initialFormData:Object.create(formData),
 formDat:Object.create(formData)
};

console.log(State)
```